update request when matching REALM
I have a freeradius configured as Proxy, I'm trying to modify request when MY_REALM is matched but he nas-identifier is never changed
realm MY_REALM {
  strip

  update request {
    NAS-Identifier := "000000"

    Called-Station-Id := "00:00:00:00:00:00"
  }


  auth_pool = my-realm-proxy
  acct_pool = my-realm-proxy

}

I'm usgin freeradiud 3.2
